# Suppress "Ignoring <ruby gem>" messages on emacs startup

Tags: init-file, message, warning, ruby

When I start emacs, I get a bunch of messages

```
Ignoring charlock_holmes-0.7.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine charlock_holmes --version 0.7.7
Ignoring escape_utils-1.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine escape_utils --version 1.2.1
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Ignoring github-linguist-7.13.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine github-linguist --version 7.13.0
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.0
Ignoring nokogumbo-2.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogumbo --version 2.0.5
Ignoring nokogumbo-2.0.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogumbo --version 2.0.4
Ignoring racc-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.5.2
Ignoring rugged-1.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rugged --version 1.1.0
Ignoring sassc-2.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.4.0
2021-04-21 00:29:41.421 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[68954:1066860] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
```

How do I suppress these messages?  I have tried doing what they ask (i.e., running `gem pristine charlock_holmes --version 0.7.7`), but nothing changes.

Of course, fixing them instead of suppressing them would be good, but I'm not sure that's an Emacs issue.

Comment: Hi Jake. I'm assuming it's a package that gives you these messages? (You can verify this by starting emacs with the `-Q` flag.) One hacky way might be to set the `inhibit-message` variable to `t` just before the offending package is loaded and reset it to `nil` right after.

Comment: @Tephra Thank you for your response :-)  Unfortunately the `-Q` flag doesn't suppress these messages.

Comment: Are the messages showing up in the terminal or in emacs?

Comment: @Tephra in the terminal

Comment: Ah, I wonder if this is some sort of brew problem? I'm on linux so unable to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using the https://emacsformacosx.com/ build of Emacs (installable directly or via `brew install homebrew/cask/emacs`.) Because of its nature as a macOS App bundle, it uses a wrapper to setup the pre-launch environment of Emacs. In this case, the wrapper is written in Ruby, and if you have any issues in your Ruby environment they'll show up. I'm not a Ruby person, but an easy test would be to comment out the `exec` call in the Ruby wrapper. Then run "emacs" again, and since we're not actually starting Emacs, if you get the same errors you'll know it's not Emacs's fault, and most likely an issue with your Ruby setup.

Something like:

```
❯ v /usr/local/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x 1 44 nega 11 May 13:44 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs*

❯ file /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs: Ruby script text, UTF-8 Unicode text

❯ vi /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs

## comment out the exec call and save and quit ##

❯ /usr/local/bin/emacs

## ruby errors here ##
```

If you're **not** using Emacs for OSX, but either the "regular" Emacs (`brew install emacs`, and symlinks directly to a Mach-O executable) or Aquamacs (an app bundle too, but with a Perl wrapper) and seeing Ruby errors, then something strange indeed is happening.